# Community Promotion Ads showing only the image

Tags: support

I suggested the advert [here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/community-promotion-ads-2014#2778) and it reached the [minimum threshold](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2761) and now it showing in the main site

> [image]

but the problem is I suggested to show the actual count of the bounties, but it simply showing the image and I seen this method in one of the SE network and I forget the network site. My question is, this advert is active or just a trial run ? if it is active how should I tell them to implement the actual count of bounties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original ad works because the image is generated from server side, and the server uses Stack Exchange API to know the number of active bounties.

[Current Ask Different bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/apple.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://apple.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

The correct one for us is the following one. I am on my iPad mini, so it's a little hard to write this answer.

[Current Drupal Answers bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/drupal.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

In the case you need to use it for other Stack Exchange sites, this is the Markdown markup to create it. Replace `<stack-exchange-id>` with the Stack Exchange identifier for the site (the subdomain currently used for the site you are interested).

```
[![Current bounties][3]][4]

  [3]: http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/<stack-exchange-id>.stackexchange.com/bounty.png
  [4]: http://<stack-exchange-id>.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct; I checked on the main site and the numbers match. I will change the ad source here.

Comment: thanks kiamlaluno !

Comment: I was almost forgetting to change the ad on the other question. `:-)` I did it now.